# Flatlist not rendering redux array data

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

My FlatList does not show any errors but is not rendering the data that I give it. The redux array is working fine and adding items to it but they are not being rendered onto the screen by the FlatList.

Whether I give it the style of flex: 1 and screen width, neither makes a difference. I am unsure if the problem is something with the data I am giving it or if the renderItem is the issue. I have a hunch it's a problem with the way redux is passing the array to the FlatList but am not positive.

The FlatList configuration of my main todo component:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: HEIGHT }}>
        <ScrollView>
          <AddTodo
            textChange={textInput => this.setState({ textInput })}
            addNewTodo={this.addTodo.bind(this)}
            textInput={this.state.textInput}
          />
          <FlatList
            style={{ flex: 1, width: WIDTH }}
            data={this.state.todos}
            extraData={this.props}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              console.log(item);
              return (
                <TodoItem
                  todoItem={item}
                  toggleDone={() => this.props.toggleTodo(item.id)}
                  removeTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    todos: state.todos
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(MainTodo);
```

My todoItem component:

```
render() {
    const todoItem = this.props.todoItem;
    console.log(todoItem);
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.todoItem}
          onPress={() => this.props.toggleDone()}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              color: todoItem.completed ? '#aaaaaa' : '#313131',
              textDecorationLine: todoItem.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none',
              fontSize: 16 }}
          >
            {todoItem.text}
          </Text>
            <Button
              title='Remove'
              color='#ff5330'
              onPress={this.props.removeTodo}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how my todo reducer is set up for the array that is being passed:

```
const todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: [...state.todos, {
          id: action.id,
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }] };
```

The add todo is working fine and adding things to my array but where the FlatList should be is blank without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access todos from state and not props. "*mapStateToProps*" Use this.props.todos and you should be good.

```
        <FlatList
               style={{ flex: 1, width: WIDTH }}
                data={this.props.todos}
                extraData={this.props}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                  console.log(item);
                  return (
                    <TodoItem
                      todoItem={item}
                      toggleDone={() => this.props.toggleTodo(item.id)}
                      removeTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
                    />
                  );
                }}
              />
```

Comment: Stuff like this is why Typescript is so awesome. I highly recommend learning it the near future, defining your props structure and data types will prevent these easy to make errors.

Comment: Ah, that's my bad I meant to change that back to props before I sent this in, however that did not fix my problem sadly I just tried :(

Comment: Finally figured it out, I needed to call todos: state.TodoReducer.todos in my mapStateToProps.